# Perl attempts to use wrong package

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

i am very new to perl. I'm leraning how to use Mechanize package. I have example page. I don't know if it is good for learning cause it works in a strange way but still, i want to understand what's happening right now.

First, i have written script which is getting directly content under page1:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Frames-> new();
my $mechFr = WWW::Mechanize::Frames-> new();
my $url="page1 url";

$mech->get($url);

my @frames = $mech->get_frames();
$mechFr= $frames[0];
print $mechFr->content();
```

And this works fine.
Then i was trying to get to this page from page0 and i have written this:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Frames-> new();
my $mechFr = WWW::Mechanize::Frames-> new();
my $url="page0url";

$mech->get($url);
$mech=$mech->follow_link(text_regex => qr/page1like/);
print $mech->content();

my @frames = $mech->get_frames();
$mechFr= $frames[0];
print $mechFr->content();
```

Content under mech afeter following link looks ok (i really am on page1), but then i get error `Can't locate object method "get_frames" via package HTTP:Headers" at (...)/Message.pm line 694"`. My package list is the same in both scripts:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Frames;
```

So my question is, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$mech=$mech=>follow_link()` is what's breaking it. You're clobbering your original $mech.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`WWW::Mechanize documentation`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-follow_link) `$mech->follow_link(...)` returns an HTTP::Response object, you assign this result into your variable `$mech`. This effectively replaces the existing value of `$mech` with an HTTP::Response object.

The HTTP::Response module has no method `get_frames()` as Perl correctly tells you.

You need to store your HTTP response in a *separate* variable:

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Frames-> new();
my $mechFr = WWW::Mechanize::Frames-> new();
my $url="page0url";

$mech->get($url);
my $http_response = $mech->follow_link(text_regex => qr/page1like/);
print $http_response->content();

my @frames = $mech->get_frames();
$mechFr= $frames[0];
print $mechFr->content();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I did see this documentation and tried simmilar thing, i guess i did something other wrong that time. Thank you!

Comment: Better: `$mech->follow_link(...); print $mech->content();`

Comment: Does it store the HTTP::Response internally as well?. I am not familiar with `WWW::Mechanize`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, yes Mechanize stores responses internally.  (Actually a stack of responses, because it has a `back` method much like a browser's back button.)